# Codeigniter: active record и LIKE точное совпадение

Tags: activerecord, like, codeigniter

Доброго времени суток.
У меня есть 2 таблицы, одна с категориями, а вторая с доп. полями для категорий, дело в том что в таблице с доп полями есть столбик "categorys" где прописаны id категорий в таком виде: "12,32,14,," что бы получить доступ к доп. полям я использую:
$this->db->like("categorys", $category->id.","); все бы нечего, но если мы захотим получить все доп поля которые привязаны к категории с id 2, то мы получим доп поля к категории 2 а так же все остальные где на конце есть 2ка т.е "12,32".
Можно ли как ни будь избежать такой ситуации, что бы именно 2ю категорию находил а не все категории у которых на конце 2?

Comment: вопрос я думаю не по теме CodeIgniter тут вопрос по организации БД
и составлении правильного запроса к ней.
Я бы сделал не так. Я думаю проще сделать таблицу категорий, таблицу доп полей и таблицу связей где будет всего три поля id / id категории / id доп поля

Comment: Да, тут согласен, но не хотел делать по 5 запросов только для того что бы вывести что то..нашел более удобный способ, т.к я заранее обрабатывал результаты, то я поставил в цикл foreach следующее
$exp_cat = explode(',', $prop->categorys);
 if(in_array($category_id, $exp_cat)) {//Вывод доп. полей}

И в итоге все получилось как надо :) спасибо за ответ, он меня заставил подумать и придти к этому элементарному способу)